# Two year Schengen visa type C with a comment 'for business'

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa type C valid for two years, and there is a comment written by issuing country on the visa that it is for business. What does that mean?

Comment: It means it was issued for business travel.

Comment: It means what it says, that it's for a bussiness purpose. If you requested another kind of visa you may want to contact the embassy again.

A link that may help you:
http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/

Comment: @Nighthunter22: Don't believe anything that website says; it is a private ad-funded website that hasn't even been kept minimally up to date (for example, it still claims that there's such a thing as 'B' visas for transit even though they were abolished in 2010!)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks for the info. I'd edit it to remove it but it's a bit late, anyway hope the OP check all the comments :).

Answer (score 1):

Since your visa is valid for two years, I will assume it is issued for multiple entries.

The Schengen rules do not provide any way to issue a multiple-entry visa that is only valid for business visits. The issuing state can write "business" in the remarks field, but at most that tells what the trip that caused the visa to be issued was about; it does not legally influence the validity of the visa.

The very point of issuing a multiple-entry visa is that it will be valid for *all subsequent short visits* within its period of validity, even if they have other purposes than the first one that the visa was issued for.

Why would the issuing country even bother to write "business" in the remarks field? Most probably it is just because they do it for *all* visas they issue, even ones with short validity where it makes sense for border guards to check that the traveler's plans match what the visa was issued for. And even for a long visa such as yours, the *first* use of the visa is generally expected to be the trip you documented in your visa application -- otherwise a suspicion will arise that the claims in your application were fraudulent *at the time you applied*, which can lead the visa being revoked at the border.

But once you *have* used the visa once for its applied-for purpose, it does not restrict what you can use it for subsequently.

Comment: Thanks Henning for the comment. I have a 2 year research project in  collaboration with a University in the issuing country. This is why they have added this comment.

Comment: The reason I am asking, is that I was travelling to the Finland which is another Schengen country, but was supposed to connect in London Heathrow, which is not a Schengen visa, and therefore, I was denied to board the plane. I did not know I needed a transit visa for the UK.

Comment: @Nadim: That is completely independent of any "business" notation on the Schengen visa. The UK requires airside transit visas of some nationalities (you haven't disclosed yours), and this requirement is _not_ waived for holders of Schengen visas (even though they do waive it for people with e.g. US visas).

Comment: Many thanks once again. I am Egyptian. Yes, they waive for group tourist visa, and D type visas which are business visas, so I was wondering if my Schengen visa C that has business in the comment, would not qualify as the D visa?

Comment: @Nadim type D is not a business visa. The difference between C and D is solely duration. Type D allows longer stays than 90 days.